# create test for activatedRoute data

Tags: angular, phantomjs, karma-runner

I want to create test for my component. I have router resolver that resolve data and read data in ng init .i want create test for that .How can i create test for this code

```
    @Component({
    selector: 'jhi-label-detail',
    templateUrl: './label-detail.component.html'
})
export class LabelDetailComponent implements OnInit {

    label: Label;

    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.route.data.subscribe(({label}) => {
            this.label = label.body ? label.body : label;
        });
    }


}
```

and route is like this

```
{
        path: 'label/:id/view',
        component: LabelDetailComponent,
        resolve: {
            label: LabelResolve
        }
    }
```

and resolve is this

```
@Injectable()
export class LabelResolve implements Resolve<any> {

    constructor(private service: LabelService) {
    }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        const id = route.params['id'] ? route.params['id'] : null;
        if (id) {
            return this.service.find(id);
        }
        return new Label();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { MyComponent } from './my-component.component';

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;
  const route = ({ data: of({ label: 'hello' }) } as any) as ActivatedRoute;

  beforeEach(
    async(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [MyComponent],
        providers: [{ provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: route }],
      }).compileComponents();
    }),
  );

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should set the label', () => {
    expect(component.label).toEqual('hello');
  });
});
```

The important thing to note here is that we are providing our own implementation of `ActivatedRoute` in `TestBed.providers`, with just one property (`data`) that is being used by our component.

Comment: `const route: any = { data: of({ label: 'hello' }) };` would be more suited. In your case, Typescript will throw an error, saying that fields are missing to cope with an `ActivatedRoute` object. And you don't need the `x as y` syntax if you type your variable at first. Otherwise, excellent answer, +1

Comment: automatically set label to label property of component?

Comment: @aliakbarazizkhani it does not change the way you should be testing the component. You can create the separate spec for your resolver.

Comment: @trichetriche thanks for pointing out the { label: 'hello' }, I've missed it. What do you mean by saying: 'if you type your variable first'?

Comment: `const route: any` instead of `const route = {} as any` is what I meant.

Comment: Ah ok. Yes, it will work, but you will not get any intellisense completion if you want to type route.data :)

Comment: @aliakbarazizkhani consider accepting this answer if It solved your problem. You can create a separate question for testing your Resolver, because it's best to keep the questions focused on a single problem.

Comment: I dont test resolver .i want to send complete source for explain better.

Comment: hu @TomaszKula i write this https://gist.github.com/azizkhani/6027c88dd12a7f79a40bfc987558ea0f but get this exception Identifier 'route' is never reassigned;

Comment: @TomaszKula do you know how we would test the same pattern, however `label$` being an Observable?

Answer (score 4):

In angular 8+ there is the RouterTestingModule, which you can use in order to have access to the ActivatedRoute or Router of the component. Also you can pass routes to the RouterTestingModule and create spies for the requested methods of route.

For example in my component I have:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.data = this.route.data
}
```

And in my test I have:

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ProductLinePageComponent ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([])
      ],
    })
    .compileComponents()
  }))

  beforeEach(() => {
    router = TestBed.get(Router)
    route = TestBed.get(ActivatedRoute)
    route.data = hot('(a)', {a: someData})
  })
```

and later in the 'it' section:

```
  it('should update', () => {
    const spyRoute = spyOn(route.snapshot.paramMap, 'get')
    spyRoute.and.returnValue('21')
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProductLinePageComponent)
    component = fixture.componentInstance
    fixture.detectChanges()
    // here you can test the functionality which is triggered by route data
    const expected = cold('(a)', {a: someData})
    expect(component.data).toBeObservable(expected)
  })
```